# React Redux: Updating object is updating state but not triggering selector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux branch structured like:

```
{
  byId: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Name 1', username: 'Username 1' },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Name 2', username: 'Username 2' },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Name 3', username: 'Username 3' },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I have a us case of triggering an action to change the name of an entry, posting to my API, returning the full object (to reflect changes locally incase of other sources manipulating my backend), and re-inserting it into my redux state.

Action:

```
changeName(id, name) => {
  // post to API
  const object = <object from API>
  dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    byId: { id: object }
  });
};
```

Reducer:

```
case 'UPDATE_USER':
  return update(state, {
    byId: { $merge: action.byId }
  });
```

I am triggering this action from a list that is rendering the rows from `byId` - I can confirm it **updates my redux correctly** however it does not cause a **rerender** of my list. If I were to trigger a different action, ie. remove a list row, the list would update to reflect the removed item, as well as the `changeName` that did not previously cause a rerender.

I know it's something to do with my `$merge` and re-inserting with the same `key` value and a deeper-nested `field` change is mixing up my redux to not notice a state change, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks

- edit: I'm also using a custom selector for this list that uses lodash/isEqual

```
export default createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize, isEqual);
```

I've also tried:

```
return update(state, {
  byId: {
    [action.id]: { $set: action.data }
  }
});
```

with no luck

Comment: 'I can confirm it updates my redux correctly however it does not cause a rerender of my list' - this is typically a problem of mutating the redux store. Can you provide the source code of the update function?

Comment: @lavor it is using [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

Comment: @Arthur update only does shallow merge. Could you share the result of `update()`?

Comment: @JosephD. how exactly could i share that information?

Comment: @JosephD. if I console log my `update()` call, I can see the new redux branch with the property value correctly updated